# Access pixel color from SDL_Texture

Tags: c++, sdl, pixel, sdl-2

My code throws an access error. This is the code:

```
SDL_Color *getPixelColor(SDL_Surface *loadingSurface, int x, int y) {

    SDL_Color getColor = {0,0,0};

    SDL_Texture *readingTexture = nullptr;
    readingTexture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, loadingSurface->w, loadingSurface->h);
    SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(readingTexture, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);

    void * vPixels;

    SDL_LockTexture(readingTexture, &loadingSurface->clip_rect, &vPixels, &loadingSurface->pitch);

    memcpy(vPixels, loadingSurface->pixels, loadingSurface->w * loadingSurface->h);

    Uint32 *aPixels = (Uint32*)vPixels;

    SDL_UnlockTexture(readingTexture);

    //Get pixel at location.
    Uint32 getPixel = aPixels[y * loadingSurface->w + x];
    Uint8 *colors = (Uint8*)getPixel;

    //cout << colors[0] << " " << colors[1] << " " << colors[2] << endl;

    getColor.r = colors[0];
    getColor.g = colors[1];
    getColor.b = colors[2];

    SDL_Color *color = &getColor;
    return color;

}
```

Exception thrown: read access violation.
colors was 0xFF00.

At any time I try to access colors. The methods described in the SDL documentation all return the same errors and there is no information on the internet save for LazyFoo (which this method is based on, and which does not work.)

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT:**

I fixed my code by re-writing it and ignoring some of the bad sources I was using to understand some parts of SDL. Here is the working code:

```
Uint32 getPixel(SDL_Surface *loadingSurface, int x, int y) {

    Uint32 *pixels = (Uint32*)loadingSurface->pixels;
    return pixels[(y * loadingSurface->pitch / 4) + x]; // I noticed that each y selection was off by 4 pixels in the y so I divided by 4. Why this is the case remains a mystery.

}
```

Why I need to divide by 4 is a mystery, and took a while to figure out. Any ideas why?

```
SDL_Color getPixelColor(SDL_Surface *loadingSurface, int x, int y) {

    SDL_Color getColor = {0,0,0};
    SDL_PixelFormat *format;
    Uint32 pixel, index;
    Uint8 red, green, blue, alpha;

    format = loadingSurface->format;
    SDL_LockSurface(loadingSurface);
    pixel = getPixel(loadingSurface, x, y);
    SDL_UnlockSurface(loadingSurface);

    index = pixel & format->Rmask;  
    index = index >> format->Rshift; 
    index = index << format->Rloss;  
    red = (Uint8)index;

    index = pixel & format->Gmask;   
    index = index >> format->Gshift; 
    index = index << format->Gloss;  
    green = (Uint8)index;

    index = pixel & format->Bmask;   
    index = index >> format->Bshift; 
    index = index << format->Bloss;  
    blue = (Uint8)index;

    index = pixel & format->Amask;
    index = index >> format->Ashift;
    index = index << format->Aloss;
    alpha = (Uint8)index;

    getColor.r = red;
    getColor.g = green;
    getColor.b = blue;
    getColor.a = alpha;

    return getColor;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
Uint8 *colors = (Uint8*)getPixel;
```

As far as I can tell from your code, `getPixel` is the 32bit RGBA pixel color value at location (x,y) in your texture. You then cast this value to `Uint8*` for some reason.

So now `colors` contains a nonsense address, equal to the pixel color value, instead of the address of `getPixel`, as you probably intended. So, when you do `colors[0]` and try to read the memory via this "address", you get an access violation.

Did you mean to take the address of `getPixel` first before casting, in order to access individual color channel values?

```
Uint8 *colors = (Uint8*)&getPixel; // Note the &
```

---

Unrelated to your exact question, but also an issue with your code: you are returning a pointer to a local variable:

```
SDL_Color getColor = {0,0,0};
// etc.
SDL_Color *color = &getColor;
return color;
```

`getColor` will go out of scope as the function returns and what the caller of your function will get is a dangling pointer.

You should rewrite your function to return `SDL_Color` by value: just `return getColor;` and change the return type to `SDL_Color`.

Comment: That, plus reading from locked texture is not really valid (it is for writing only), even more so if it was unlocked already. I have no idea why function named `getPixelColor` would suddenly create a texture, but it should read from source surface pixels, not texture.

Comment: I'm following the instructions from the SDL documentation and from one of the only other sources on the internet about this, LazyFoo. Reading from a Surface is even worse and does not work, according to the notes in the documentation.

According to the documentation, for pixel access to occur at all I must lock the Surface or Texture.

Comment: @EmZee But you already do read from a surface, when you do `memcpy()` of pixels from the surface into your locked texture, so I think @keltar has a point: there is no reason for you to bother with creating a texture (which you forgot to free, by the way) at all, when you could simply read the needed pixel value from original surface's pixels.

Comment: @EmZee LazyFoo is often incorrect. `SDL_LockTexture` doc explicitly says it is write-only, so technically you can't read from it (in most cases you can if you just written data into it - but what's the point? - but it is not guaranteed to persist after unlock), but you unlocked it first and then try to access pointer than may no longer be valid (e.g. SDL may allocate tmp buffer for locked texture, free it on unlock - what you're accessing now? garbage or even segfault). For surfaces it is not so clear but, unless RLE, you can access `pixels` without locking. Why you need texture is unknown.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I ignored LazyFoo and instead worked only from the SDL doc. I carefully controlled what type of bitmap image I was working with and got it functioning.